# Save an std::vector<int> to file

Tags: c++, serialization, vector, c++03

I noticed, that when using:

```
std::vector<int> v(100000);
...
std::ofstream outfile("outfile.dat", std::ios::out | std::ofstream::binary);
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(outfile));
outfile.close();
```

my `std::vector<int>` is not serialized as raw bytes data (4 bytes per `int`) but as string, i.e. the string representation of each integer is saved to disk, which I don't want.

**How to save a `std::vector<int>` as binary data?**

(Note: I'd like to learn it with standard C++03, before learning new methods for it).

Comment: Yeah, output stream iterator assumes you want text. If you don't care about portability, you can `outfile.write(v.data(), v.size()*sizeof(int));` If you do care about portability, read up on Endianness and write a suitable fixed width integer rather than `int`.

Comment: Saving as binary without respecting [endian concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) is a recipe for trouble.

Comment: @user4581301 It works indeed, with a cast to (char *) for the first argument. I'll accept it if you post as an answer.

Comment: Gak. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To write binary data, use [`std::ostream::write()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) instead of [`std::ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) (which uses `operator<<` internally, thus formatted output), eg:

```
std::vector<int> v(100000);
...
std::ofstream outfile("outfile.dat", std::ofstream::binary);
outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(v.data() /* or &v[0] pre-C++11 */), sizeof(int) * v.size());
outfile.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::ostream_iterator` writes values to the stream using its `operator<<`. Elements are written as if you used `outfile << value` for each member of the vector, which means converting values to text.

So, what you want to do instead is define a class that serializes itself to the stream in a binary representation, eg:

```
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<BinaryInt>(outfile));
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^
```

Now you have to define the `BinaryInt` type so that it can be constructed by an `int` value but serialize itself via `operator<<` appropriately:

```
struct BinaryInt
{
    int value;
    BinaryValue(int v): value(v) {}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, BinaryInt const& bi)
    {
        // convert bi.value into a binary representation.
        // Note C++ does not define a specific size for int.
        // Nor does it define an endianess.
        // Nor does it define a specific representation.
        // So to be cross platform/OS/compiler you will need to define these
        // and convert the integer into this representation.
        //
        // return str.write(<data>, <size>);
        //
        // If this is just a test the following would work
        // but is extremely brittle for the long term.

        return str.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&bi.value), sizeof(bi.value));
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a bit lost with `friend`, (re?)definition of operator `<<`, specific use of a new `struct`, and expression like `BinaryValue(int v): value(v) {}`. (probably because I come from plain C). Isn't there an easier solution than redefining all of this?

Comment: @Basj: That is about the simplist way to do it. Or you could just write a loop and use C.

Comment: @LokiAstari: this is not the *simplest* way to accomplish the task, but it is a *C++-ish* way to do it (and one that I have used before). A *simpler* way is to just call `outfile.write()` one time to write the entire vector array in one go, since its data is stored in contiguous memory. But, to deal with size and endian issues, this is a good solution, since the `operator<<` can perform the necessary transformations before calling `write()`

Answer (score 0):

Might I recommend a saner way of doing it by using Protobufs? I will not type the code, but if you are working on a project, do not reinvent the wheel.

Using a protobuf would allow you to save the "type" of your data along with the data, and it would help you to extend your code with minimal fuss.